# How could I change a vector which has points into a vector which has their value

Tags: c++, vector

I just has a vector like that

```
vector<User*> users;
```

I know it is not a good programming style...

now I have a function

```
vector<User> getAllUser(void)
{
}
```

What I had tried is

```
vector<User> getAllUser(void)
{
    vector<User> result;
    for (vector<User*>::iterator it = users.begin(); it != users.end(); it++)
    {
        result.push_back(**it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Could someone to help me? Thankyou very much. I am just a beginner to STL

Comment: What is the user interface declared as?

Comment: `result.push_back` instead of `result.push_bach` . Also, please elaborate on "it didn't work"

Comment: Try `push_back` instead. Also, please accept answers that have been useful.

Comment: It should of worked, what actually happened? I would guess no copy constructor on class `User`. Could you show us the code for `User`?

Comment: @Etan  sorry, in fact, it was `push_back`

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry for my wrong spelling, it was `push_back`

Comment: @john  you meant I should write a code of copy constructor on clas `User`?

Comment: @Laurent: Without seeing your code for `User` I can't say, but it's definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code should work, but you made a typo:

```
result.push_bach(**it);
```

`push_bach` is not a declared function for `std::vector`, so I'm assuming that's where the error lies. I would recommend you get a decent compiler, which should point this error out to you right away, without having to go through stackoverflow.

To fix, use the proper method name, `push_back` instead:

```
result.push_back(**it);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use pointers, use a nice `std::shared_ptr<User>` wherever you would use `User*`, and don't mix and match heap and stack allocated objects.

If you didn't really need to use pointers everywhere, make sure that `User` has a copy constructor defind (eg, `User::User(const User& rhs) { /* ... */ }`)